# Is a GEE regression unnecessary when replicate weights are used?

Tags: regression, generalized-estimating-equations

I am running regressions on census microdata.  So far I have been using weighted least squares regressions with standard errors calculated from replicate weights, but I have been asked to consider using GEE to account for correlated disturbances created by multiple points coming from the same household.  I have done a little reading on GEE and it seems that its advantage is more accurate standard errors, rather than improved coefficients. If that is the only reason to use GEE over WLS I shouldn't bother because I am calculating SEs with replicate weights, and would throw out the model's weights.  If the coefficients are somehow better it may be worth considering.

Is there any reason to use GEE here? If so, I would appreciate any advice on how to set up a GEE regression with sample weights, since that seems to be tricky and possibly unsupported.  I am using python, but might be able to use R if it were absolutely necessary.

Comment: Consider the question, is estimation by maximum likelihood appropriate for your data? GEE's are not only used for standard errors. You should be aware the GEE's don't use maximum likelihood, where maximum likelihood assumes estimated a full distribution. GEE's may be useful if you are sure about the correlation structure of your data. GLS may be more useful to you than WLS as well if you know the correlation structure.

Comment: See the section on disadvantages for WLS http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm